# How to save audio in WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp, storage, audio, nokia-lumia-800

Is there any way to save an audio recording on WhatsApp to my phone? I have been sent a few recordings of friends singing and I don't know how to save the actual audio onto my phone without having to listen to it through WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can not save the audio to your phone.

*Maybe this will be possible in a future update since we now got the Files application.*

Comment: Some things from WhatsApp are now being stores in the file system. Try browsing your phones file system via the Files application and your computer and see what you can find.